# SQL Query, possible to do in one query?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to write a query that does the following:

I have two tables:

```
 SalaryRanges: id, beginRange, endRange
 UserInfo: id, salary,...
```

I would like to have a query that does the following:

Give me a list of ids of SalaryRanges where there are more than 5 persons meeting that specific range for each salary range.

So something like:

SalaryRange ids: 1, 4, 5, 7 have 5+ people meeting their respective salary ranges.

Is this possible to do in one query? Or do you need to break the query up into different calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just from the top of my head but I think it would work

```
SELECT  sr.id
FROM    SalaryRanges AS sr
INNER JOIN  UserInfo AS ui ON ui.Salary >= sr.beginRange AND ui.Salary <= sr.endRange
GROUP BY    sr.id
HAVING count(ui.id) > 5
```

Ok the updated version using BETWEEN as per the comment

```
SELECT  sr.id
FROM    SalaryRanges AS sr
INNER JOIN  UserInfo AS ui ON ui.Salary BETWEEN sr.beginRange AND sr.endRange
GROUP BY sr.id
HAVING count(ui.id) > 5
```

Both should work though